# Render array with br tag but gets object object instead

Tags: reactjs

I would like to see this result when rendered.

```
text1
text2
text3
```

But I'm getting [object object] or "
" instead in my text.

This is my attempt to render the text.

```
import React from 'react';

const FunctionalApp = () => {
  let changes = [];
  changes.push("text1");
  changes.push("text2");
  changes.push("text3");
  return (
    <span>
      {
      changes.map((change) => {
        return (change + <br/>);
      })
      }
    </span>
  )
}

What seems to be issue here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `{}` to render react variables

```
changes.map((change) =>  
      <>{change}   <br/> </>
   )
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qmmirm?file=test.tsx,App.tsx)